# What is SubplotZero? (documentation lacking)

Tags: matplotlib

## My question

I would like to know what matplotlib's `SubplotZero()` function does, knowing that it is not referenced in matplotlib's documentation, but is used in at least three examples of the matplotlib [website](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html) ([here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/axisartist/simple_axisline2.html#sphx-glr-gallery-axisartist-simple-axisline2-py) for instance). Also, since it is not present in the documentation is it recommended and safe to use? Or is there a risk it might be removed in future versions of matplotlib?

---

## The context

I want to make a plot with matplotlib that displays the "zero" axis. Examples of such plots are shown in matplotlib's `examples` page. This is done with

```
ax.axis["xzero"].set_visible(True)
```

However, writing

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.axis["xzero"].set_visible(True)
```

yields error

```
ax.axis["xzero"].set_visible(True)
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

Instead, as was shown in the examples, one is supposed to write **(Note: actually there is another way to achieve the same result: see @ImportanceOfBeingErnest's answer)**

```
from mpl_toolkits.axisartist.axislines import SubplotZero
fig = plt.figure()
ax = SubplotZero(fig, 1, 1, 1)
fig.add_subplot(ax)
ax.axis["xzero"].set_visible(True)
```

which indeed works. However, I was curious to understand what the `SubplotZero()` function did, and why it existed in the first place (after all why is it needed at all?). So I went to look in the documentation and realized it was not part of it!

Does someone know the answers to those questions?

Comment: in addition to the answer below, you might also find the comments in the code in the github repo useful for understanding how a `SubplotZero` is different to a normal `Axes` instance: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/mpl_toolkits/axisartist/axislines.py#L17

Comment: Note that I never said that the use of the axisartist would not be recommended. What I said was that it is (especially for new users) often very hard to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, so there are three questions here.

#### Where is the `SubplotZero()` documentation?

It's currently not documented, since it's an `AxesZero`, which is augmented to the subplot status via

```
SubplotZero = matplotlib.axes.subplot_class_factory(AxesZero)
```

`AxesZero` is also not documented, but at least appears in the documentation.
In general, the complete `mpl_toolkits.axisartist` is very poorly documented and is missing in the current documentation completely. But one may refer either to an [older version](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/index.html) or the [current devdocs](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/toolkits/index.html).

It should not be removed in future versions.

#### What is the reason for the `TypeError`?

The error `TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable` tells you that a method cannot be indexed.

This happens here as the `axis` of a `SubplotZero`, which is a `mpl_toolkits.axisartist.axislines.AxesZero`, is completely different from the "usual" `matplotlib.axes.Axes`. The former provides its individual axes as part of a dictionary which can be accessed as `ax.axis["xzero"]`. The latter is a method, which needs to be called and does some modifications on the axes, e.g. `ax.axis("off")` turns the axes off. It is indeed quite unfortunate that they both have an attribute `axis`, refering to completely different things in the end.

#### How to create an axis at zero position?

While the `mpl_toolkits.axisartist` module provides this functionality as shown in the quoted [example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/axisartist/simple_axisline2.html), the use use of this module is admittedly (due the missing/incomplete documentation) rather cumbersome.

An alternative is to use usual `matplotlib.axes.Axes`. To position a spine at zero position one could refer to the [Spine placement demo](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/ticks_and_spines/spine_placement_demo.html).

To recreate the linked example with the xaxis spine at zero y position, one would e.g. do

```
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('data', 0))
```

using an ordinary `matplotlib.axes.Axes` instance `ax`.

Complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title('x axis spine at zero data coordinate')
x = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)
ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))
ax.set_xlabel("Axes zero")

ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('data', 0))
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Perhaps I should consider changing those examples on matplotlib.org to something similar to what you are suggesting? Do you know whether I would be allowed to do that, and if so how?

Comment: Those examples are part of the `axisartist` documentation and appear in the [Axisartis section of the gallery](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html#axis-artist). Their purpose is to show how to use the axisartist toolkit and should hence not be changed to something unrelated. The [Spine placement demo](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/ticks_and_spines/spine_placement_demo.html) basically shows already how to do the same with "normal" axes (and appears in the [ticks and spines section](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html#ticks-and-spines).

Comment: That being said, you are welcome to suggest improvements to the documentation. See the [developper's  guide](https://matplotlib.org/devel/index.html) on how to do so. In short, this would be done by creating an issue or directly a pull request on [Github](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib).

Comment: Oh ok, understood!